# Access to sandboxed app ios that i am not the owner

Tags: ios, sandbox

I want know if there are ways to access a sandboxed ios app that i am not the owner. For example, consider youtube. In particular I would like to be able to interact with the interface of youtube: touch the play button or other buttons such as "share" or other. 
So I would like to access views and interact with them. I do not want to use for this purpose the screenshot. I am interested in whatever method exists. To be clear I am ready even to jailbreak the device if necessary. But I do not think is the case. I own developer account .
Any idea?

Comment: Can't be done. One app can't poke into another app.

Answer (score 0):

> I want know if there are ways to access a sandboxed ios app that i am not the owner.

Nope. That's the point of sandboxing. You could look into what URLs are exposed by the YouTube app, though.

> To be clear I am ready even to jailbreak the device if necessary.

If you're willing to jailbreak you can become root and have full access to the device. Look into the methods from BSD for reading / writing other processes memory. You'll probably have to learn some ARM assembler as well.

Note, this will make things possible, but certainly not easy. What are you trying to accomplish? There's almost certainly an easier way to achieve your use case.

Comment: I would like to create a tool for testing different app. Youtube was just an example. 
I would like to take advantage of the methods or functions that already exist to create different tests. 
For example if i want touch the share button on youtube I would call the method "shareexample ()" to do this. 
Your solution, though complicated is interesting. 
Can you give me some advice on how to get started? 
Or have any other ideas?

Comment: I'd look into Hopper (http://www.hopperapp.com/) for disassembling. OS X (and presumably iOS) don't implement procfs, so you'll need to read up about the memory accessing functions exposed by the kernel as well. Most of this is beyond my ability to help out with, unfortunately.